# Getting a NaN error, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, math

I have this code in JavaScript:

```js
SolarPanels = parseInt(lRemainingWidth / (panel_width + ( 2 * lPanelInterSpace)));
```

and then I alert the `SolarPanels` value which gives `NaN` as output,

```js
alert("SolarPanels "+SolarPanels);
```

This 1 line is a tiny part of a huge calculation, but my code seems to fail here,
with the use of alerts i've read out the values of `SolarPanels`, `lRemainingWidth`, `panel_width` and `lPanelInterSpace`
which are the following:

```
lRemainingwidth = 17.4.320227272727276
SolarPanels = 0
panel_width = 1.65
lPanelInterSpace = 0.02
```

I think it has to do with the 2 dots in `lRemainingWidth`, either way, I don't know how to fix it. Why the `lRemainingWidth` has 2 dots?

---

Update :

This is the part that calculates the lRemainingWidth :

```js
    if(HalforDouble === "Yes")
    {
        lRemainingWidth = (roof_ridge /2) + ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge);            
    }

    else
    {
        lRemainingWidth = roof_ridge + (2 * ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge));
    }
```

The values here are:

```
lRemainingWidth = 0
roof_ridge = 17
lRemainingHeight = 20.769000000000002
lRoofEdgeDegrees = 83.5169263071276
lRoofEdge = 0.2
```

Comment: Probably some of your variable values is / are not what you think. `console.log()` or `alert()` them before calculation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you mix strings and numbers

Start with this code before any computation :

```
var roof_ridge = parseFloat(roof_ridge);
```

There might be other strings hidden in your code but we don't see them. Apply the same conversion on them.

Comment: This seemed to help, thanks alot, the problem was that i got the roof_ridge out of a cookie as a string, parseFloat helped! Thanks alot! I will tag it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> lRemainingWidth = roof_ridge + (2 * ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge));
> ```

If `roof_ridge` is a string then the `+` does string concatenation instead of addition.

Change this to

```
lRemainingWidth = +roof_ridge + (2 * ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge));
```

The prefix `+` operator in `+roof_ridge` coerces its argument to a number.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a cornerstone of the issue in `roof_ridge` variable. This variable is instance of String class, not a number. So, when you code go to this line:

```
lRemainingWidth = roof_ridge + (2 * ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge));
```

the next calculation is done:

```
'17' + whatever_float_value = got string concatenation instead of number's sum.
```

To fix this just add:

```
lRemainingWidth = parseFloat(roof_ridge) + (2 * ((lRemainingHeight / Math.tan((lRoofEdgeDegrees * Math.PI) / 180)) - lRoofEdge));
```